# Are questions about private tutors ok?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Its been a while since I studied the language and I'm considering a private tutor. Are questions regarding this appropriate for this site?

Thanks

**EDIT #1:**

Some possible questions:

- How much should\would one expect to pay a private tutor?
- Should natural\native language tutors be preferred to non-native?
- How would one go about finding a tutor? Is cold calling universities and high schools an acceptable means? Craigslist posting doesn't seem to work very well.
- Are there any unions or trade groups that one would be able to contact to find tutors?
- Should tutors also be teachers, or is it acceptable to simply have bi-lingual people to talk with? Has anyone had experience with this - if so, has it it worked out well or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your list of possible questions, I would have to say no.  Your questions would have similar answers if you were trying to find a French (or indeed, math) tutor, for instance, so they do not belong on a site specifically about the Japanese language.

Comment: By far the best and most logical response. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Not in my opinion as I fail to see how this is related to the language itself.

What question(s) were you thinking of asking? If anyone had a tutor to recommend?

Comment: I've added a list of possible questions as an edit.

Answer (score 3):

Though it depends on the specific question, questions about private tutors probably fall into the "too localized" category:

> This question is unlikely to ever help any future visitors; it is only relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet.

The questions on this site are supposed to be useful to a wide variety of visitors.  If all you're doing is asking "Who is the best private tutor in Washington?" it's not really helpful to all of the people outside of the state (probably most of the site), and would likely be flagged as "too localized" by the community.  (Not to mention you probably won't get a good answer because the number of people who can answer that question is really small.)

On the other hand, if you can find a non-subjective question that would apply to a lot of people about private tutors and is somehow related to the Japanese language, it would probably be OK.

Comment: I've added a list of possible questions as an edit.

Comment: @java I'm not sure you'll get good answers to those questions on this site.  The answers to #s 1, 3, and 4 probably depend on where you live, and the other two seem subjective - at best you'll probably just get a bunch of personal experiences.  To me, they all seem off-topic.